# to replace using find word in array from text file

Tags: php, arrays, filter, chat, str-replace

I have problem that str_replace can't replace the second to last word... first word is working then second up to last is not work in array.. I tried enter the message "ducker apple banana chicken" in "chat.php?message=" then become like this:

output:

`"***er apple banana chicken"`

badwords.txt:

```
duck;
apple;
banana;
chicken;
water;
```

chat.php

```
$censoredfilter = file("badwords.txt");
$censoredfilter = implode("\n", $censoredfilter);
$censoredfilter = explode(";", $censoredfilter);

$message = $_GET['message'];

for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($censoredfilter);$i++)
{
    $message = str_replace($censoredfilter[$i], "***", $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect usage of implode there no?

```
$censoredfilter = file_get_contents("badwords.txt");
$censoredfilter = explode(";\n", $censoredfilter);
```

Alternatively,

```
$censoredfilter = file_get_contents("badwords.txt");
$censoredfilter = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $censoredfilter);
$censoredfilter = explode(";", $censoredfilter);
```

Comment: As @ben has said below, depending on what OS you're running, or indeed what text editor you're running, new-line characters might be either "\n" or "\r". Removing both of them just attempts to account for all situations :)

Answer (score 6):

`str_replace(array('things', 'go', 'here'), '', $text)`

should replace anything value in the array found in the text with nothing

```
$censoredfilter = file("badwords.txt");
$censoredfilter = implode("\n", $censoredfilter);
$censoredfilter = explode(";", $censoredfilter);

str_replace($censoredfilter, '***', $_GET['message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @dogmatic69's answer I'd also consider removing the ;'s from your badwords.txt file and shorten the code to just this:

```
$censoredfilter = file_get_contents("badwords.txt");
$censoredfilter = explode("\n", $censoredfilter);

$message = str_replace($censoredfilter, '***', $_GET['message']);
```

Also be aware that if badwords.txt is editable by anyone else their text editor may use different line endings e.g. \r\n, or \r causing your script to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the ;'s an alternative solution is:

```
$censoredfilter = file("badwords.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$message = str_replace($censoredfilter, '***', $_GET['message']);
```

This works because `file()` actually returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached. Adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag removes the newlines from the end of each element. See the [php manual on file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for more info.

It also has the added benefit of handling any of the usual line-endings.